# Seit wann sind Dirnen nicht mehr anständig?

Tags: meaning, word-choice

Der erste Satz  Grimms Rotkäppchen lautet:

> Es war einmal eine süße Dirne, die hatte jedermann lieb...

Dem Kontext nach bedeutet in diesem Satz "Dirne"  nichts Anderes als  "Mädchen".
Seit wann hat sich die Bedeutung zu etwas weniger unschuldig verwandelt und warum?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Eigentlich muss man hier zwei Fragen beantworten:

- Wann begann der Ruf der Dirne Schaden zu nehmen? und
- Wann hat die Dirne ihre Unschuld ganz verloren?

Laut [Wikipedia](https://de.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirne) war die Dirne zunächst eine junge Frau, auch höheren, dann in der Bedeutung verengt auf eine Frau niederen Standes, also eine Dienerin oder Magd.

Ab dem 13. Jahrhundert tauchen erste Konnotationen mit sexueller „Freizügigkeit“ auf, im 15. Jahrhundert dann die Verbindung zur gewerbsmäßigen Prostitution; im 16. Jahrhundert schaffte es die „Dirne“ als Synonym zur „Metze“ ins Wörterbuch.

Noch war die Moral der Dirne nur angeknackst, sie konnte sich ihren Lebensunterhalt – sprachlich betrachtet – sowohl mit ehrbarer Arbeit als auch im horizontalen Gewerbe verdienen.

Das änderte sich dann zum Ende des 18. Jahrhunderts, wenn Johann Christoph Adelung (Germanist u. Lexikograph) den Begriff Dirne für höhergestellte Damen als „im Hochdeutschen beynahe veraltet“ und für Frauen einfachen Standes als nur noch in Niedersachsen gebräuchlich bezeichnet.

Trotzdem darf Rotkäppchen bei Grimm noch Anfang des 19. Jahrhunderts „Dirn(e)“ heißen, Fontane lässt 1889 seinen [Herrn von Ribbeck auf Ribbeck](https://de.m.wikisource.org/wiki/Herr_von_Ribbeck_auf_Ribbeck_im_Havelland_(Fontane)) die Birnen der „Lütt Dirn“ schenken und auch heute ist sowohl im Platt („Deern“) als auch im Bayerischen („Dirndl“) die Dirne als moralisch unangezweifeltes junges Mädchen erhalten. Außerhalb des Dialekts ist der gute Ruf allerdings seit rund zweihundert Jahren dahin.

Comment: Vielen Dank für die interessante Antwort, Stephie.

Comment: Ich kenne noch das Volkslied "Spannenlanger Hansel, nudeldicke Dirn, gehen wir in den Garten, pflücken wir die Birn'n...". Was Spannen sind ist mir bis heute ein Rätsel, bis zur ersten Dampfnudel war auch "nudeldick" befremdlich (Spaghetti!). "Dirn" kannte ich erst nur aus dem Lied, später dann kam die Bedeutung des Freudenmädchens/Hure/Bordsteinschwalbe/... dazu. Häufig ist 'Dirne' für Prostituierte aber heute auch nicht mehr.

Comment: @User http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Spanne#Bedeutung2b

Comment: @Matthias: Oh, das ist ja eher klein - dachte immer das wäre jetzt irre lang.

Comment: @userunknown: Zu klein für meinen Geschmack. Wäre vielleicht was für eine neue Frage, was genau damit gemeint ist.

Comment: Als ich jünger war, kannte ich das »Dirndl« als wertfreies Synonym für »Mädel« (Mädchen jünger als ca. 12-15 Jahre) und als Bezeichnung für eine bestimmte Art von Frauenkleidern. Für Prostituierte kannte ich damals nur »Hur« (ohne *e*; Ich war dann auch erstaunt, dass es einen Film namens »Ben Hur« gab) und »Nutte« (*Nutte* wurde aber seltener verwendet). Das war in der Steiermark (Südosten Österreichs) vor ca. 1985 (bin 1965 geboren).

Answer (score 3):

Der klassische Fall einer semantischen Bedeutungsverschlechterung. Dirne ist heute in der Standardsprache ein negatives Wort. Dirn(e) oder Deern hat allerdings in Märchen, Kinderliedern oder im nordeutschen Raum (Plattdeutsch) noch seine ursprüngliche Bedeutung.

Plattdeutsches Lexikon: Deern
http://www.plattdeutsches-woerterbuch.de/pages/plattdeutsches_woerterbuch.html

Man muß Deern ins Suchfeld eingeben und auf "abschicken" tippen.